# How to get result from using subquery

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL to get some additional information from database. I am trying to do widget bar:

[image]

Here is table structure:

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE category in (SELECT name FROM category where id='5')
```

What i want is i need to display category names and products numbers.

But above query gives me empty result set. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You forgot to mention what your query is supposed to do.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only my assumption, since there is little info

This query gets a list of categories and for each adds a count of products having id of that category

```
select c.id, c.name, count(p.id) count 
   from category c 
      left join 
        product p 
      on p.category = c.id   
   group by c.id
```

You will get rows with category id, category name, product count

Comment: can you explain your query ?

Comment: I've written into the answer